# Same settings for all projects in an Azure DevOps Organization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-services

In my Azure DevOps organization, there are multiple projects.

I need to ensure, that all projects accross the same organization have the same repository settings for

- Pull request policies with Work item linking and one approver
- default branch name
- ...

As of now, i can set this settings only on project level:
[image]

How can these settings be made (or at least monitored) at organization level for all projects?